# Showing a class element

Tags: jquery

```
<div class= "movies">
    <div class= "movie-tools pull-right rd-region">
        <span class="rd-main" style="display: none;">Release Date: 
            <span class="releaseDate-View">2014-09-25</span>
            <a href="#" class="update-releaseDate"><img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon ic_b_edit"></a>
        </span>
        <span class="rd-data-tool">
        <input type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" id="dp1413878193903"> 
        <span class="sched-ea-tool"> 
            <a class="submit-updated-release" href="#"><img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon submit-updated-sched "></a>
            <a class="cancel-update-release" href="#"><img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon ic_s_cancel"></a>
        </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.rd-region').on('click', '.cancel-update-release',function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('.rd-data-tool').hide();
        $this.parent().sibling('.rd-main').show();
});
```

I'm having problems with showing the `rd-main` class because by default, its hidden. But when the user clicks the `cancel-update-release` class,
the `rd-main` class should be shown and the `rd-data-tool` should be hidden (that's what the jquery code should do).

The `$this.closest('.rd-data-tool').hide();` works fine but the `$this.parent().sibling('.rd-main').show();` doesn't. I think, it's not pointing to the correctly. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please make fiddle and let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think its the matter of an typo in sibling = siblings function

```
$this.closest('.rd-data-tool').hide().siblings('.rd-main').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

because `rd-main` is not a sibling of the parent(`sched-ea-tool`) of `cancel-update-release`, it is the sibling of `rd-data-tool` so

```js
$('.rd-region').on('click', '.cancel-update-release', function() {
  $(this).closest('.rd-data-tool').hide().siblings('.rd-main').show();;
});
```

```css
.rd-main {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "movies">
  <div class= "movie-tools pull-right rd-region">
    <span class="rd-main" style="display: none;">Release Date: 
      <span class="releaseDate-View">2014-09-25</span>
      <a href="#" class="update-releaseDate"><img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon ic_b_edit"/></a>
    </span>
    <span class="rd-data-tool">
      <input type="text" class="datepicker hasDatepicker" id="dp1413878193903"/> 
      <span class="sched-ea-tool"> 
        <a class="submit-updated-release" href="#"><img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon submit-updated-sched "/></a>
        <a class="cancel-update-release" href="#"><img src="assets/images/_.gif" class="icon ic_s_cancel"/></a>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the `rd-main` class is still hidden when i changed the code to that